# React Native Expo EAS Build Error - Android

Tags: android, react-native, expo, eas

I'm getting an error for my EAS build for ':expo-modules-core' & I'm not able to build via expo build:android.

The full error is below:

```
[stderr] * Where:
[stderr] Build file '/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules- 
core/android/build.gradle' line: 185
[stderr] * What went wrong:
[stderr] A problem occurred evaluating project ':expo-modules-core'.
[stderr] > Could not find method prefab() for arguments [true] on object of type 
com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.LibraryBuildFeaturesImpl.
```

I've tried installing expo modules but having no luck. I've tried so many things... PLEASE HELP!!

Thanks

Comment: have you tried following the build error troubleshooting guide? https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/troubleshooting/

Comment: @brentvatne - I've tried to go through the troubleshooting but can't seem to find a fix, app is working locally and I used to be able to build via expo builds fine, but then for some reason I can't do that any more.

Comment: refer to the bottom of the troubleshooting guide where it provides guidance on how to ask a question to get help

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with react-native and the solution was remove the problematic folder.

In this case:

```
rm -fR /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core
```

Maybe it's in a wrong state (if you are upgrading your expo version).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33918537)

Comment: I've tried to comment but got the message: "You must have 50 reputation to comment". The question was about how to compile when that message is given. So the solution that worked for me is removing the old cache folder. Why it doesn't provide an answer?